# After switching to a new window driver cant find elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

I have page with a button which upon pressing opens a new popup window.
I can successfully navigate to the popup window but the driver still throws an error:

> No Such Element

The code is as follows:

```
    String pwindow = this.getDriver().getWindowHandle();
    genPage.clickByXpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/div/div[2]/span/a/img");

    Set<String> allWindows = this.getDriver().getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(allWindows);
    String[] windows = allWindows.toArray(new String[allWindows.size()]);
    System.out.println("[" + windows[0] + ", " + windows[1] + ", " + windows[windows.length - 1] + "]");

    System.out.println("Title : " +  this.getDriver().getTitle());
    System.out.println("Current Url : " + this.getDriver().getCurrentUrl());
    System.out.println("Window : " + this.getDriver().getWindowHandle());
    System.out.println("Parent Window : " + pwindow);
    System.out.print("\n");

    this.getDriver().switchTo().window(windows[windows.length - 1]);
    //this.getDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
    //this.getDriver().switchTo().frame("searchFrame");
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [selectWindow | name=searchFrame | ]]
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [waitForPopUp | lookup | 30000]]

    System.out.println("Title : " +  this.getDriver().getTitle());
    System.out.println("Current Url : " + this.getDriver().getCurrentUrl());
    System.out.println("Window : " + this.getDriver().getWindowHandle());

    genPage.insertById("id", "keys"); //cant find this element or any after
    genPage.clickByName("go");
    genPage.clickByLinkText("Name");

    this.getDriver().switchTo().window(pwindow);
```

The methods from genPage:

```
public void clickByXpath(String xpath){
    WebElement ele;
    ele = this.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    ele.click();
}

public void clickByLinkText(String link){
    WebElement ele;
    ele = this.getDriver().findElement(By.linkText(link));
    ele.click();
}

public void clickByName(String name){
    WebElement ele;
    ele = this.getDriver().findElement(By.name(name));
    ele.click();
}

public void insertById(String id, String data){
    WebElement ele;
    ele = this.getDriver().findElement(By.id(id));
    ele.sendKeys(data);
}
```

Any help as to what is wrong or what I have missed would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Scott

Comment: you sure that your xpath is actually correct? that's incredibly specific, and even a slight change in the page html structure will invalidate it.

Comment: Sorry, the problem occurs at insertById, the xpath is fine.

Comment: could you provide your code for your "genPage"?

Comment: an excerpt from the #selenium IRC channel regarding your xpath: `omg… that xpath. i like big xpath and i can not lie, you other testers can't deny, when a DOM walks in with a lengthy stack trace and some slashes in your face you get hung."`

Comment: added the relevant methods from the genPage class above.

Comment: wait for the element to be available then.Go with WebDriverWait

Comment: Check that the page does not contains a frame or iframe...also try using dynamic xpaths and try not to have  pop-up methods in genpage...keep that a separate... :)